# Excel one row to many, based on column data

Tags: excel

I've got an Excel file with over 10k rows, which looks like

### ID |DATA1| DATA2

### 1  |Text | 13;15;16

### 2  |Text2 |13;12

I need to expand numbers in DATA2 field using delimeter ";" to a new rows:

### ID|DATA1|DATA2

### 1 | Text|  13

### 1 | Text|  15

### 1 | Text|  16

### 2 | Text2| 13

### 2 | Text2| 12

Is it possible to do it with Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with VBA. Open the Macros in MS Excel and insert this code.

```
Sub todo()
 lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 rowNum = lRow
   For r = 1 To lRow
    symbolCounter = UBound(Split(Cells(r, 3).value, ";")) + 1
    textVal = Split(Cells(r, 3).value, ";")
      For c = 1 To symbolCounter
        rowNum = rowNum + 1
        Cells(rowNum, 1).value = Cells(r, 1).value
        Cells(rowNum, 2).value = Cells(r, 2).value
        Cells(rowNum, 3).value = textVal(c - 1)
      Next c
   Next r
End Sub
```

Should work.I checked.

Comment: Thanks! That's brilliant, i've updated this code to my needs, and it fits perfect for me.

Comment: Always happy to help.